# Electric field of point charge

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, singularities

[image]

in above picture, we have two point charge ( same size ).
Does electric field of q2 at location of q1 depend on size of q1?
because we know when we want to measure electric field of a charge, use another test charge which it is very small.but two charge have same size here.

Answer (score 4):

No it doesn't. The electric field at a point is defined as $$\vec E=\frac{1}{q} \vec F$$ in which $\vec F$ is the force on the test charge *q* placed at that point. The force $\vec F$ is itself proportional to *q*, so the division by *q* makes the field strength $\vec E$ independent of *q*.

Ideally we define $\vec E$ as the limit as *q* approaches zero of $\frac{1}{q} \vec F$. The reason for doing this is so that the test charge *q* doesn't alter (by attraction or repulsion) the positions of the 'source charges' whose field it is supposed to be measuring. If, in your case, the source charge, q2, is firmly fixed it doesn't matter if the test charge *isn't* approaching zero.

Comment: I use F= kq1*q2/r^2 to measure force on q1. Can we use E =F/q1 to measure electric field on position of q1? consider q1 is not small.

Comment: Yes. That's it. The field strength at the position of q1 is therefore $$\vec E=\frac{k q_2}{r^2} \hat r.$$ This is independent of q1, as it should be.

Comment: this is correct when q2 fixed? correct?

Comment: Yes. If q2 (the 'source charge') $weren't$ fixed, we'd need to make sure that the test charge (your q1) was very small.

Comment: this electric field is for which point?

Comment: The point at which you place the test charge (your q1, my $q$).

Answer (score 2):

Each charge generates its own electric field. The total field is obtained by adding up the contributions of all charges. This is a consequence of the linearity of Maxwell's equations.

So no, the field generated by $q_2$ alone is oblivious to the presence of other charges. The total field however is the sum of the fields produced by both charges. Note that the field is not defined at the exact position of a point charge though. The Coulomb potential diverges at these points.

However, since a charge does not exert a force onto itself, charge $q_2$ feels the electric field from charge $q_1$ alone.

Comment: I use F= kq1*q2/r^2 to measure force on q1. Can we use E =F/q1 to measure electric field on position of q1?

Comment: @user3728644 Yes.

Comment: It is correct when q2 does not move and fixed. yes?

Comment: @user3728644 Sure, you need to keep the source fixed. That's why the "test-charge" is often assumed to be very small so as not to influence the source charges.

Comment: but you said electric field is not defined at the exact position of q1. therefor E=F/q1  is for which point?

Comment: @user3728644 Wherever you want to determine the electric field due to $q_2$ as long as that point doesn't coincide with the position of $q_2$. That would necessitate bringing both charges to the same point which is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand about size you take it on a wrong way ,size means magnitude of a charge and  it is govern by formula Q=ne (number of electron ) and secondly he test charge is taken in small magnitude q so that it doesnt effect charge distribution of source charge .

Answer (score 0):

The electric field is defined as the force per unit charge. It is best to use a small test charge in order to avoid secondary effects on your measurement due to the field of the test charge, but on principle it is independent of the amount of test charge.